# How to get a view controller to retain all of its views/contents even when its currently not shown?

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have set up navigation slide-out navigation panel using [SWRevealViewController](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController) similar to the ones used by Facebook or Gmail app, and have several view controllers including a "main" view controller that programmatically adds views that are created (or "drawn) by the user.

My issue is, when the user navigates to another view controller and back to the "main" view controller again, all the programmatically added views disappear, and the user is left with a the default blank canvas view. How would I be able to retain all of the views/contents that are placed in the main view controller so that it will be there when the user navigates back to this view controller?

For reference, I've included the code in my `SideMenuController`:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue: (UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id) sender
{

    if ([segue isKindOfClass:[SWRevealViewControllerSegue class]]) {
        SWRevealViewControllerSegue *swSegue = (SWRevealViewControllerSegue *)segue;

        swSegue.performBlock = ^(SWRevealViewControllerSegue* rvc_segue, UIViewController* svc, UIViewController* dvc) {

            UINavigationController* navController = (UINavigationController*)self.revealViewController.frontViewController;
            [navController setViewControllers: @[dvc] animated: NO ];
            [self.revealViewController setFrontViewPosition: FrontViewPositionLeft animated: YES];
        };
    }

}
```

Also: I have tried various other pre-made slide-out navigation panels such as [ViewDeck](https://github.com/Inferis/ViewDeck) and [MFSideMenu](https://github.com/mikefrederick/MFSideMenu), and I run into this issue with all of them.

**Update**

As some of you suggested, I should make a *strong pointer* to my main view controller from my App Delegate. How would I be able to do this, so that when I set up my segues from the menu controller, when it sees that its going to my main controller it automatically pulls what was previously there, instead of instantiate everything anew and calls viewDidLoad, etc?

Thanks!

Comment: I haven't used SWRevealViewController, so I don't know if this is possible, but you just need to make a strong property to the main controller, and go back to that same instance -- it sounds like it's creating a new instance the way it works now. In the terminology of the SWRevealViewController, which is the main controller? Front, back,side? Something different?

Comment: If the same viewcontroller is being pushed in the navigation stack then the views once added should still be there. Pls log your navigation stack to see if it contains the view controller

Comment: Maintain a strong pointer from App delegate or Make a global pointer (in app plist) etc. There are literally many number of ways to achieve this.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! @rdelmar The "front" is the main controller, and "back" menu controller. Will log the nav stack and then update the question body.

Comment: I don't know how to create a strong pointer to my main controller in the App delegate, and didn't find a SO post that details how to do this - is there a guide/tutorial that I could check out on how to do this?  Thanks!